# Redirect traffic to CDN page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So anytime someone visits this page:

```
http://www.site.com/page/image_(.*).png
```

They get redirected to the cdn url, which would be

```
http://cdn.site.com/page/image_(.*).png
```

How can I do that using htaccess? I only need this for that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_alias, if you have access to vhost config, in your main vhost (for www) add:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/image_(.*)\.png http://cdn.site.com/page/image_$1.png
```

If you don't have access and have to use an .htaccess file, you need mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/image_(.*).png http://cdn.site.com/page/image_$1.png [R=301,L]
```